# Trying to use filter pipe and async pipe

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to use data retrieved from webservice using async pipe aswell as filter but causes my data not to be retrieved on the front end. I have the pipe setup correctly just not sure how to use two pipes or even if this will work on a webservice call filtering?

```
    <div class="search-hero">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <div class="row card-group">
          <div class="col-4 "*ngFor="let accident of webService.accidents_list | async | filter:searchText" >
```

Comment: could you provide a code for `webService.accidents_list` creation?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?